# Clone a function in Julia

Tags: julia

I want to overwrite a function in Julia using its old definition. It seems the way to do this would be to clone the function and overwrite the original using the copy — something like the following. However, it appears `deepcopy(f)` just returns a reference to `f`, so this doesn't work.

```
f(x) = x
f_old = deepcopy(f)
f(x) = 1 + f_old(x)
```

How can I clone a function?

Background: I'm interesting in writing a macro `@override` that allows me to override functions pointwise (or maybe even piecewise).

```
fib(n::Int) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
@override fib(0) = 1
@override fib(1) = 1
```

This particular example would be slow and could be made more efficient using [`@memoize`](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/Memoize.jl). There may be good reasons not to do this, but there may also be situations in which one does not know a function fully when it is defined and overriding is necessary.

Comment: presuming you meant `f(x) = 1 + f_old(x)`?

Comment: But... why?  Essentially you're asking to work around the fix for the (previously) infamous [bug #265](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/265).  There are ways to do this, but they're likely to be fragile.

Comment: Added some notes on what motivated this question

Comment: An IMHO better approach to implement your macro would be to make a `@pointwise` macro, taking a `begin` block with a fixed number of function definitions instead, and converting it to one definition. ([PatternDispatch.jl](https://github.com/toivoh/PatternDispatch.jl) seems to do what you propose, but is rather old.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can do this using [IRTools.jl](https://github.com/MikeInnes/IRTools.jl).

(Note, on newer versions of IRTools, you may need to ask for `IRTools.Inner.code_ir` instead of `IRTools.code_ir`.)

```
using IRTools

fib(n::Int) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

const fib_ir  = IRTools.code_ir(fib, Tuple{Int})
const fib_old = IRTools.func(fib_ir)

fib(n::Int) = n < 2 ? 1 : fib_old(fib, n)

julia> fib(10)
89
```

What we did there was captured the intermediate representation of the function `fib`, and then rebuilt it into a new function which we called `fib_old`. Then we were free to overwrite the definition of `fib` in terms of `fib_old`! Notice that since `fib_old` was defined as recursively calling `fib`, not `fib_old`, there's no stack overflow when we call `fib(10)`.

The other thing to notice is that when we called `fib_old`, we wrote `fib_old(fib, n)` instead of `fib_old(n)`. This is due to how `IRTools.func` works.

According to Mike Innes on Slack:

> In Julia IR, all functions take a hidden extra argument that represents the function itself
>   The reason for this is that closures are structs with fields, which you need access to in the IR

Here's an implementation of your `@override` macro with a slightly different syntax:

```
function _get_type_sig(fdef)
    d = splitdef(fdef)
    types = []
    for arg in d[:args]
        if arg isa Symbol
            push!(types, :Any)
        elseif @capture(arg, x_::T_) 
            push!(types, T)
        else
            error("whoops!")
        end
    end
    if isempty(d[:whereparams])
        :(Tuple{$(types...)})
    else
        :((Tuple{$(types...)} where {$(d[:whereparams]...)}).body)
    end
end

macro override(cond, fdef)
    d = splitdef(fdef)
    shadowf = gensym()
    sig = _get_type_sig(fdef)
    f = d[:name]
    quote
        const $shadowf = IRTools.func(IRTools.code_ir($(d[:name]), $sig))
        function $f($(d[:args]...)) where {$(d[:whereparams]...)}
            if $cond
                $(d[:body])
            else
                $shadowf($f, $(d[:args]...))
            end
        end
    end |> esc
end
```

Now one can type

```
fib(n::Int) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
@override n < 2 fib(n::Int) = 1

julia> fib(10)
89
```

The best part is that this is nearly as fast (at runtime, not compile time!) as if we had written the conditions into the original function!

```
n = 15

fib2(n::Int) = n < 2 ? 1 : fib2(n-1) + fib2(n-2)

julia> @btime fib($(Ref(15))[])
  4.239 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
89

julia> @btime fib2($(Ref(15))[])
  3.022 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
89
```

Comment: Thanks! I am having trouble if I replace Int64 with Any. Have any ideas on why this might cause a problem?

Comment: Where did you replace `Int64` with any? in `IRTools.code_ir(fib, Tuple{Int})`? If so, the problem is that you never defined a method for `fib(::Any)`, you defined a method for `fib(::Int)`, so there is no IR available to manipulate for `fib(::Any)`.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't see why you'd want to do this (there must a better way to get what you want!).

Nonetheless, although not exactly equivalent you can get what you want by using anonymous functions:

```
julia> f = x->x                    
#3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f_old = deepcopy(f)         
#3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f = x->1+f_old(x)           
#5 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f(4)                        
5
```

Comment: More likely is that I want something a little silly :) I'm interested in a macro that allows me to override a function pointwise. Added some details to the question.