# Duplicating functions in Julia

Tags: function, julia, updating, cloning

I need to overwrite a function based on its previous definition, and this leads to a stackoverflow error.
I have tried with deepcopy(f), but it just returns a reference to f, so this doesn't work.
What I need to be able to do over and over is:

```
Old(x) = pdf(Uniform(),x)
New(x) = updating_function(Old, Y1)
Old(x) = deepcopy(New(x))
New(x) = updating_function(Old, Y2)
[...]
```

EDIT:
My overall goal is to have a function that takes a prior distribution and spits out a posterior with an unusual signal structure due to my application.
A simple running example of this would be

```
Old_pdf(x)= pdf(Uniform(),x)
Old_mean=0.5

function BU(d,low)
value, tol = quadgk(Old_pdf, Old_λ, 1)
truncated(λ)=d(λ)/value
end

Newpdf=BU(Old_pdf,Old_mean)
Old_mean, tol= quadgk(x -> Newpdf(x)*x, Old_mean, 1)
Old_pdf=BU(Old_pdf,Old_mean)
```

I know that this example could be addressed with functions from the Distributions package. It's not the case for my application.

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400828/clone-a-function-in-julia) and read the documentation of the IRTools package, but I am unable to make this work. In particular when I try

```
Old(x) = pdf(Uniform(),x)
New(x) = updating_function(Old, Y1)
const Old_ir= IRTools.Inner.code_ir(New, Tuple{Int})
Old(x) = IRTools.func(Old_ir)
```

I obtain an object that doesn't behave like a function, hence generates methods error in the rest of the code. I made several attempts at this, and it is entirely possible that I am missing something trivial.

Comment: Is there some specific reason anonymous functions not meet your use case? Something like `updating_function(x -> pdf(Uniform(),x), Y1)`? It's difficult to know exactly what you require without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: With `code_ir`, you have to pass the tuple of types of the method you want. Which with a PDF is probably `Float64`, not `Int`.

Comment: But probably, you should explain what your overall goal is. Using IRTools to duplicate functions is only the right approach in very few, weird cases.

Comment: Right, thank you. I edited to provide MCRE. My BU function is fairly longer and messier, so for clarity I am not using anonymous functions.

Comment: I did tried substituting Int with Float64 @phipsgabler, but I still got the same error. My goal is to have a function that takes a prior distribution and bayesian-updates it, but the signal structure is a bit unusual ad ad hoc.

Comment: That still sound very much like a case for a couple of recursively stacked anonymous functions to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
Y1 = 5.0
Y2 = 7.0
updating_function(f1,c) = x -> 2.0 * f1(x) + c
Old = x->sqrt(x)
New = updating_function(Old, Y1)
Old = New
New = updating_function(Old, Y2)
```

Comment: That was my original syntax, and how I got the stackoverflow error with my updating function. The fact that your code runs, and the bit I have posted above doesn't, adds to my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need anonymous functions:

```
function BU(f, λ, y)
    # I guess here you would use the observations `y` in some way?
    z, _ = quadgk(f, λ, 1)
    return λ -> f(λ) / z
end

mean(f, λ) = quadgk(x -> f(x) * x, λ, 1)[1]

original_pdf(x) = pdf(Uniform(), x)

f = original_pdf
λ = 0.5
for y in Y
   f = BU(f, λ, y)
   λ = mean(f, λ)
end
```

Now I tried very hard, and I think I understand what you're doing, but the example you gave wasn't very clear.  Consider this conceptual.

Such things make nice [folds](https://vixra.org/abs/1606.0328), by the way.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for taking the time to answer, and I apologize for the lack of clarity. I followed the structure of your suggestion, and I now I don't get the overflow error anymore. I don't quite get exactly what broke the self-reference that was leading to the error, but anonimous function within my update() function seems to have done the trick. I'll look into folds too, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: `f(x) = bla` and `f = x -> bla` just are very different things in a way. A closure lexically captures its environment, whereas a function redefinition will change the meaning of all references to it.