# Can I redefine a function, but still use the old definition within the new definition?

Tags: julia

**Context**

In my projects, I generate various figures and other binary files. I aim to detect any changes in these files without including them in Git due to their large size. My proposed solution involves adding companion files that store a checksum, only these companion files will be tracked by Git.

**Example**

Consider a scenario where I use a hypothetical `Plot` package, which provides a `save(filename::String, fig::Figure)` function. My objective is to redefine the `Plot.save` function in a way that it additionally saves a companion file containing only a checksum.

```
using Plot

function Plot.save(filename::String, fig::Figure)
    write(filename * ".chksum", string(hash(fig)))
    Plot.save(filename, fig) # <- PROBLEM: this line causes infinite recursion, 
                             #             I need to call the original definition
end
```

**Question**

The problem I am currently facing is how to invoke the original `Plot.save` function from within this new definition. Is there a way to accomplish this?

---

**Update** I found a quite similar problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/58423251/2001017

Comment: I think this could be type piracy... why don't just give another name to your modified function ?

Comment: @Antonello The idea was to do not have to modify my already existing code. But yes, that's type piracy.

Comment: in *Python(, that's just redefining a name and wrapping the code it references (`foo = wrap(foo)`), with "decorating" being a special case of it.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thank for the suggestion. I do not think there is an equivalent approach in Julia. I just found another post that addresses this problem (see my post update), however the trick is more complicated as you have to duplicate the Julia function code.

Comment: I suspect that macros are the facility to let you do this but I'm not sure

Comment: You can define a `save` function without importing it (no prefix of `Plot.`). This will override all calls to `save` within the top module. Then in the function body, you can call `Plot.save()` to access the version inside Plot. May not be advisable in a package, but it could work locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this as long as the functions are defined in different modules, and as long as the code you're hoping to intercept isn't specifying the module.

A real-world example:

```
import Plots

function plot(args...)
    println("my plot func")
    Plots.plot(args...)
end

julia> plot([1, 2, 3])
my plot func # plot generated in window

julia> Plots.plot([1, 2, 3])
# nothing printed, plot generated in window
```

But this kind of thing probably isn't advisable in a package you intend to register for public use.